# Simulating normal distribution on "level surfaces"

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, monte-carlo, simulation

What is a basic way to simulate points on the "level surfaces" of a multivariate normal distribution? That is, for a mean vector $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$, how do we generate $X\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$ such that the PDF $f_{\mu,\Sigma}(X)$ is equal to a constant $c$?

Given the form of $f_{\mu,\Sigma}$ this boils down to generating points $X\sim N(\mu,\Sigma)$ that satisfy $(X-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(X-\mu)=c$.

What if we instead have a multivariate $t$-distribution? I imagine the algorithm would be similar because the level surfaces of a multivariate $t$-distribution are also defined by $(X-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(X-\mu)=c$.

Comment: Would this be helpful?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Drawing_values_from_the_distribution  -- in the final step if you feed in, instead of $z$, some $\alpha z/|z|$, that might achieve what you want, because $\alpha z / |z|$ are the equi-pdf surfaces of $z \sim N(0, I)$.  Not sure how to translate from your $c$ to $\alpha$ though.